# mark struct as unmanaged in C# - Unity ECS Baker

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct, unmanaged, rider

I'm dealing with new ECS package (com.unity.entities) and have following code in my Monobehavior:

```
public class LevelBaker : Baker<LevelMono>
{
    public override void Bake(LevelMono authoring)
    {
        AddComponent(new LevelProperties
        {
            SpawnDimensions = authoring.SpawnDimensions,
            NeutralSpawnCount = authoring.NeutralSpawnCount,
            NeutralActorPrefab = GetEntity(authoring.NeutralActorPrefab)
        });
        AddComponent(new LevelRandom
        {
            Value = Random.CreateFromIndex(authoring.RandomSeed)
        });
    }
}
```

Code runs ok, but Rider highlights the `AddComponent` method with

> The type 'ComponentsAndTags.LevelProperties' must be valid unmanaged
> type (simple numeric, 'bool', 'char', 'void', enumeration type or
> non-generic struct type with all fields of unmanaged types at any
> level of nesting) in order to use it as a type argument for 'T'
> parameter

error as it has the definition like this a:

```
public void AddComponent<T>(in T component) where T : unmanaged, IComponentData
```

LevelProperties and LevelRandom are simple structs, containing only unmanaged types, but Rider seem to not know it. Here's code of LevelProperties:

```
public struct LevelProperties : IComponentData
    {
        public float2 SpawnDimensions;
        public int NeutralSpawnCount;
        public Entity NeutralActorPrefab;
    }
```

How can I "mark" the LevelProperties struct as unmanaged so Rider would stop highliting it as an error?
I'm using newest, current version of Rider and Unity 2022.2.0b16. Code compiles and runs, only Rider shows error.

Answer (score 0):

Structs are unmanaged when their fields and properties are also unmanaged. The use of `Entity` as a type is probably the reason it is considered managed.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types

Comment: But Entity is an unmanaged type, its part of ECS and it's sole purpose is to be unmanaged part of the unmanaged struct used by ECS

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself:

- Make sure Both `LevelProperties` and `LevelRandom` are `struct`s (this is what fixed it for me).
- Make sure you're using `Unity.Entities` for `Entity` and `Unity.Mathematics` for `float2` and `Random`. Any other `Random` package and it will error.